# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 403.)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, back4app

I am using sdwebimage and back4app backend . We are not able to load image from back4app.

```
 [immg1 sd_setImageWithURL:url11 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pro"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                if (error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"B4A_Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    NSLog(@"B4A_Error URL: %@", imageURL.absoluteString);

                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog (@"B4A_Success");
                    [immg1 setNeedsDisplay];
                }
            }];


//            [immg1 setImageWithURL:url11 usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];


           [imgView addSubview:immg1];
```

Comment: can you make sure the online image exists? because this error occurs due to the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason your `SDWebImage` wasn’t persisting the `user-Agent`. I manually forced it to persist before every call. Just try this:

```
 NSString *userAgent = @"";
            userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@ (%@; iOS %@; Scale/%0.2f)", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *)kCFBundleExecutableKey] ?: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *)kCFBundleIdentifierKey], [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"] ?: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey], [[UIDevice currentDevice] model], [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion], [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];

            if (userAgent) {
                if (![userAgent canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]) {
                    NSMutableString *mutableUserAgent = [userAgent mutableCopy];
                    if (CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)(mutableUserAgent), NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [:^ASCII:] Remove", false)) {
                        userAgent = mutableUserAgent;
                    }
                }
                [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
            }
```