# Not retrieving any image from url(issue couldn't perform the operation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, sdwebimage

We are using `SDWebImage` and some times it is giving the result and Some time it is not retrieving any image. And having the issue of operation couldn't perform.

```
NSString *strImageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseUrlImage,model.strThumbnail];

strImageUrl = [strImageUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[cell.imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]]
```

;

Comment: Could you please post detailed error message.

Comment: Read and use this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145676/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-403-the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-ns/40145751#40145751